# Intellij says Vaadin flow lumo theme css variables not found

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Then working on my new Vaadin 14 based application Intellij cannot find the built in lumo theme variables...

[image]

These variables exist at runtime in my browser, but where can I point Intellij to see them?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's not possible, at the moment, unfortunately.

The problem is that starting from V14 styles you want to reference are packaged as`.js` files, but styles are written in `.css`. For example, if in V13 you could import them in your template like this [Sizing and spacing](https://cdn-origin.vaadin.com/vaadin-lumo-styles/1.0.0/demo/sizing-and-spacing.html):

`<link rel="import" href="bower_components/vaadin-lumo-styles/sizing.html">`

This would be the current way in V14 instead, which is a js file:

```js
<script type=“module”>
import “@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/sizing.js”;
</script>
```

So you can use those custom variables in your styles without problems, as long as you load an appropriate js module on your page (like this `@JsModule(value="@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/sizing.js")` [Lumo](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.9/com/vaadin/flow/theme/lumo/Lumo.html)), but I haven't found a way (and not sure there is one) to make Intellij aware of them.

---

So the underlying problem is that you can't import a variable from a js file into a css file.